# Changing Color in DataGridview rows C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I now there are a lot of other people who asked the same question and got an answer. but in my case i cant seem to get this to work. I have read a couple of posts that suggests using DefaultCellStyle on each row. I have done the same but i the colors do not change.

this is my code:

```
private void MyHistoryMainControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    editedShipmentGrid.DataSource = handler.GetEditedShipments();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in editedShipmentGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[54].FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[55].FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this code in the Load method of the UserControl i am using. The data loads fine in the DataGridView but the colors do not change. I also checked the bool  value of my condition and it it should change color. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: This should work. Do the `row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color...` lines actually run? If you set a breakpoint on them, is the breakpoint actually hit?

Comment: yes they do. is there a property i have to set on the DataGridView ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not re-binding the datasource elsewhere?

Comment: Its a new project. I only have one method and this datagridview

Comment: I have found the solution guys. Thank you for the help. I have answered my question if you want to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I had to bind the data right after the InitializeComponent(); method. And in my Load method i change the colors depending on a cell value..

this is the solution:

```
public MyHistoryMainControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    editedShipmentGrid.DataSource = handler.GetEditedShipments();
}

private void MyHistoryMainControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in editedShipmentGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[54].FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[55].FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move your color change code within `DataBindingComplete` eventhandler you don't have worry where you have to set the datasource :)